# What are the numbers of $6,5,4$-element subsets of $\{1,2,...,10\}$ which have no three consecutive integers?

Tags: combinatorics

**Origin.** Yesterday I posted a somewhat similar question asking about the number of subsets of $\{1,2,...,n\}$ which do not contain three consecutive integers. That one was solved completely, and I have had a fairly well understanding. However, I have been intrigued to count by brutal force. So here I am: picking $n=10$, I am now stuck at the cases for the numbers of $6,5,4$-element subsets.

---

**My attempt.** I was thinking about the $6$-element case. My strategy was through coloring each of the ten integers with either yellow or red, and restricting that no three consecutive yellow's are allowed, and for each legitimate coloring I collected those yellow's into a satisfying subset. For the $7$-element case, the only four ways for distributing the three red's are $(3,6,9),(3,6,8),(3,5,8),(2,5,8)$. For the $6$-element case, I was pondering how to step from the $7$-element case by swapping a yellow with a red; excluding a red, I know there are $10$ ways, but I have no idea how to add back the red without over-counting. Any idea or hint would be appreciated. Thank you!

---

**Remark.** Thanks to the hints of lulu and Taussig, I have solved my question completely through two distinct counting approaches for which I have posted two answers accordingly. Personally, I feel that the recursion method is more algorithmic and logically concise, while the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle way provides somewhat quicker computation once I get the core idea. In terms of writing a computer program, I think that the recursion approach would definitely nail it. Nevertheless, as an enthusiastic maths student, the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle approach is definitely worth a go.
*Last, though this problem has been resolved, any new approach or idea is always welcome!*

Comment: These things are best done recursively.  A good $6$ element subset either misses $10$ (in which case it is a good $6$ element subset of the first $9$ natural numbers), or it has $10$ but not $9$ ( in which case the rest of it is a good $5$ element subset of the first $8$ natural numbers) or it contains $10$ and $9$ but not $8$ (in which case the rest of it is a good $4$ element subset of the first $7$ natural numbers).  Keep going like that.

Comment: You could also use the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle to exclude subsets with three consecutive integers.  However, this requires some care since sets of three consecutive integers can be disjoint (two separate groups of three consecutive integers) or overlapping (four consecutive integers).

Comment: Hi, lulu. Thanks for the great hint. I just posted an answer based on your hint. Could you please review it? Thanks a lot! @lulu

Comment: Hi, Taussig. Thanks for suggesting this approach. I had a rough try in which things got pretty tedious and I gave up. By the way, if you do not mind, please help me review my answer posted below based on lulu's hint. A lot of thanks. @N.F.Taussig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to lulu's hint. I am trying to write out the complete solution below.

Let $a_{i,j}$ denote the number of $i$-element subsets of $\{1,2,...,j\}$, where each of such subset does not involve three consecutive integers.

Now, let us think recursively by *partitioning* the set of such $i$-element subsets into three *disjoint* sets:

- For such $i$-element subsets which do **not** contain $j$, there are $a_{i,j-1}$ of them.
- For such $i$-element subsets which contain $j$ but do **not** contain $j-1$, there are $a_{i-1,j-2}$ of them.
- For such $i$-element subsets which contain $j$ and $j-1$, they must **not** contain $j-2$, and there are $a_{i-2,j-3}$ of them.

Hence, $a_{i,j}=a_{i,j-1}+a_{i-1,j-2}+a_{i-2,j-3}$. Then for my posted question in which $i=6$ and $j=10$, let us write out the recursion and expand!

$a_{6,10}$
$=a_{6,9}+a_{5,8}+a_{4,7}$
$=(a_{6,8}+a_{5,7}+a_{4,6})+(a_{5,7}+a_{4,6}+a_{3,5})+(a_{4,6}+a_{3,5}+a_{2,4})$
$=a_{6,8}+2\cdot a_{5,7}+3\cdot a_{4,6}+2\cdot a_{3,5}+a_{2,4}$
$=(a_{6,7}+a_{5,6}+a_{4,5})+2\cdot(a_{5,6}+a_{4,5}+a_{3,4})+3\cdot a_{4,6}+2\cdot a_{3,5}+a_{2,4}$
$=(a_{6,6}+a_{5,5}+a_{4,4})+a_{5,6}+a_{4,5}+2\cdot(a_{5,6}+a_{4,5}+a_{3,4})+3\cdot a_{4,6}+2\cdot a_{3,5}+a_{2,4}$
$=(0+0+0)+0+1+2\cdot(0+1+2)+3\cdot6+2\cdot\left({5 \choose 3}-3\right)+{4 \choose 2}$
$=45$

For the sake of completeness, without the algebraic layout, let me state here that $a_{5,10}=126$ and $a_{4,10}=161$.

Comment: The algebra certainly has the right form...I did $a_{4,10}$ hastily and got $163$...but I did not debug carefully, so the error might well be mine.

Comment: Well, I found one bug in mine, but it goes the wrong way.  Now I am getting $164$.  I'm still not confident of my result, though.

Comment: Using the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle, I get $\binom{10}{4} - 8 \cdot 7 + 7 = 210 - 56 + 7 = 161$, which agrees with your answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, guys. There is still one thing which gets me frustrated. By using the general recursion formula from my previous post, I got $504$ for the number of such subsets of $\{1,2,...,10\}$; then by applying this current post's recursion, I got $509$ by summing up $a_{0,10},a_{1,10},...,a_{10,10}$. They do not match! I have checked so many times and still could not figure out why. Please help. @lulu

Comment: Hi Taussig. Since for one comment I can only @ one user, please see my preceding comment in which I really need help. Thanks a lot! @N.F.Taussig

Comment: Check your $i = 5$ case.  Using the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle, I get $\binom{10}{5} - 8\binom{7}{2} + 7 \cdot 6 + 6 - 6 = 252 - 168 + 42 + 6 - 6 = 126$.

Comment: You are right, Taussig. Thank you so much for figuring that out for me! I am going to try the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle approach thoroughly tomorrow, because it seems easier in this case in terms of computation than the recursion approach. @N.F.Taussig

Comment: Hi, Taussig. I applied your Inclusion-Exclusion Principle approach and posted another answer accordingly. If you do not mind, please kindly have a quick check on that to ensure that my understanding is alright. A lot of thanks. @N.F.Taussig

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Taussig's hint for using the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle. I have tried it by myself. I am posting this approach as another answer for future reference.

Let $a_{i,j}$ denote the number of $i$-element subsets of $\{1,2,...,j\}$, where each of such subsets does not contain three consecutive integers.
Let $E_{m,n}$ denote the event to involve $n$ consecutive integers starting from $m$. For example, $E_{1,3}$ represents the event to have integers $1,2,3$.
Let $N(E_{m,n})$ denote the number of such subsets that satisfy $E_{m,n}$.
**Note.** $E_{m,n}$ changes meaning when the corresponding $a_{i,j}$ changes.

Okay. Now let us do the counting!

- $a_{4,10}$
  $=\binom {10}{4}-(N(E_{1,3})+N(E_{2,3})\cdot\cdot\cdot+N(E_{8,3}))+(N(E_{1,3}\cap E_{2,3})+N(E_{2,3}\cap E_{3,3})+\cdot\cdot\cdot+N(E_{7,3}\cap E_{8,3}))$
  $=210-7\times8+1\times7$
  $=161$
- $a_{5,10}$
  $=\binom {10}{5}-(N(E_{1,3})+N(E_{2,3})\cdot\cdot\cdot+N(E_{8,3}))+(N(E_{1,3}\cap E_{2,3})+N(E_{2,3}\cap E_{3,3})+\cdot\cdot\cdot+N(E_{7,3}\cap E_{8,3}))+(N(E_{1,3}\cap E_{3,3})+N(E_{2,3}\cap E_{4,3})+\cdot\cdot\cdot+N(E_{6,3}\cap E_{8,3}))-(N(E_{1,3}\cap E_{2,3}\cap E_{3,3})+N(E_{2,3}\cap E_{3,3}\cap E_{4,3})+\cdot\cdot\cdot+N(E_{6,3}\cap E_{7,3}\cap E_{8,3}))$
  $=252-\binom {7}{2}\times8+7\times6+6-6$
  $=126$
- $a_{6,10}=45$. I am leaving the details to you so that you could possibly have some fun!

Comment: While I have not yet checked the $i = 6$ case (in either of your solutions), the work you have included here is correct.

Comment: Hi Taussig. No worries; the $i=6$ case is correct in both. My endeavor to this particular question is complete now thanks to your kind help. A lot of sincere thanks. @N.F.Taussig